# Git: Print a hashtag in a custom log format

Tags: git

How can I create a custom log format where the start of the line has a hashtag (#)

I have already the format I want with a dash in my git aliases:

```
lpr = log -10 --reverse --format=format:'- %Cgreen  %s%n%Creset%b'
```

The problem clearly is that # is the comment and should be escaped. I don't find how that is done.

The final goal is to be able to create markdown formatted log messages where the first line is a title.

Comment: Not sure I understand. This shows me a `#` and then the short commit IDs: `git log --pretty='#%h'`

Comment: "*# is the comment and should be escaped.*" Sure. All possible ways. Escape (protect from the shell) with a backslash: `\#`. Or use quotes: `'#'`, `"#"`.

Comment: Being pedantic: that's a _hash_, not a hashtag. #metoo is a hashtag

Comment: @knittl Thx for the explanation
#ilearnedsomethingnew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the git alias with a `#`, and it seems to work as expected:

```bash
C:\my\repo>git config alias.lpr "log -10 --reverse --format=format:'- %Cgreen  # %s%n%Creset%b'"
C:\my\repo>git lpr

-   # Subject commit 3
Body 3

-   # Subject commit 2
Body 2

-   # Subject commit 1
Body 1
```

The strong quotes `'log ... # ...'` means you do not have to escape the `#`.

Rendered markdown:

[image: markdown]

Meaning

Comment: I had the following in my .ginconfig which didn't work:
`lpr = log -15 --reverse --format=format:'### %Cgreen  %s%n%Creset%b'`

Adding the quotes `"` work:
`lpr = "log -15 --reverse --format=format:'### %Cgreen  %s%n%Creset%b'"`

Comment: @Alvaro Yes, the double-quotes are important. The command I mention (`git config alias.lpr "..."`) will preserve said double-quotes in the Git config file.